# Task cannot continue because ECJ is not installed -- in Eclipse ant

Tags: eclipse, ant, installation

I have some ant task which says on first run

```
Task cannot continue because ECJ is not installed.

ECJ was automatically installed. Please rerun your task.
```

When running with standalone `Ant`, it runs ok second time. I don't know what is `ECJ`, but apparently it is installing in standalone `Ant`.

Contrary when running with `Eclipse` `An`t this message persisting, i.e. `ECJ` is not installing into `Eclipse'` `Ant`.

How to fix the situation?

Answer (score 14):

[This page](http://www.liferaysolution.com/2012/09/solve-ecj-error-in-liferay-ide.html#.UZS8CrV9Lhg) helped me:

1. In Eclipse, Go To Window->Preferences->Ant->Runtime
2. Select "Ant Home Entries (Default)"
3. Add External JAR... `ecj.jar`. Available in the `lib` folder of the [Liferay Plugins SDK](http://www.liferay.com/downloads/liferay-portal/available-releases).
4. Ant should now be able to compile from your `build.xml`

Comment: But is it possible to acquire autoinstall made?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but i just used the newest `ecj.jar` that [Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/) found. It should come with Eclipse, [as core part of JDT](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-using_batch_compiler.htm), but Java loves to hide classes and i hate looking for them.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar issue **In Windows**.I did below thing.

There is one jar file(ecj.jar) inside ${ant.home}/lib folder.That file was not rechable. Setting environment variable ANT_HOME_PATH to apache ant.solved my issue.

Note:  Point that variable to ant home and not to bin directory.